# WAN and LAN through network splitter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, wan

Like working on my home network and it is time to buy a mesh network, however I want to have all devices connected to the LAN wall mounts. Here is the problem; [image: Click to see image]

My ISP modem is at the front door and not the ideal location. The first LAN wall socket is in the living room, so this would be the most central location for the main mesh router (A). This means, because the A must be connected to the second device (B), to connect B to A, I have the WAN and LAN cable through a LAN splitter sending his packets via the same socket. B is than connected via the LAN wall socket on the second floor (or first floor if you are European).

I have read something about VLAN, does this apply to the solution, or is it simply not possible? And will my speed remain 200 Mb/s?

Comment: Speeds will not be the same. If you split a LAN cable, instead of 8 cables, only 4 are used for traffic, which limits the stream to 100Mbit/s. VLAN only applies to a network segment, not something inside a cable. Ideally, you would look for connecting the wall outlet near the door to one near the router, and use another port near the router to connect other devices.

Comment: you might want to look into another solution. some of the products being sold as "MESH", are absolute junk. also, don't use these network adapters, i haven't seen a single one that passes even CAT-5 verification on a fluke networks cable analyzer. the reason is because they always have straight gold pins next to each other internally. (NOT Twisted).

Comment: I basically need the router in the living room and a seamless handshake between the access points. From what I know I can achieve this with the Ubiquiti products too but those dont support MU-MIMO. I work from home often and need reliable internet throughout. So I cannot use a splitter like this to keep the download speed as-is? https://www.allekabels.nl/netwerk-kabel/191/1169560/netwerk-splitter-cablesharing.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIx5z_s7zQ2gIV1cmyCh08PQ3uEAQYBCABEgK8qvD_BwE

Comment: Get a switch, don't use these adapters. What you are describing is AP-roaming, not mesh. And it has been covered many times in super user.